# Area under the curve $f(x)=x^3$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Since $f(x)=x^3$ is an odd function so integrating it from $-1$ to $1$ will be zero by the property of definite integral.
If we integrate this function from $0$ to $1$ we get $1/4$ and from $-1$ to $0$ we get $-1/4$. Area can’t be negative so taking absolute value of both parts we get $1/2$.
What am I doing wrong?
Please explain it.

Comment: what are you doing?

Comment: And why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: I thought that both values should match

Comment: The integral yields an *algebraic* area, i.e. an area with a sign. If you want the areain the geometric sense, you're doing exactly what has to be done.

Comment: @Bernard thanks .

Answer (score 2):

As you know the definite integral doesn't find the area, but the *signed* area, in the sense that regions below the $x$-axis count negatively towards the value of the integral. The area between the graph of $y=x^3$ and the $x$-axis between $x=-1$ and $x=1$ is given by
$$\left|\int_0^1x^3dx\right|+\left|\int_{-1}^0x^3dx\right|=\frac14+\frac14=\frac12,$$
but the total *signed* area is given by
$$\int_{-1}^1x^3dx=\int_{0}^1x^3dx+\int_{-1}^0x^3dx=\frac14-\frac14=0.$$

Comment: So unless it is mentioned that we have to find signed area , it means we just need to find area bounded by the curve by taking absolute value?

Comment: I think that you should ask your professor

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your words, I believe that you misunderstand the meaning of integrating a function, which leads to the **signed area** under a function, instead of the **area** under a function. More specifically speaking, **signed area** means that the area below the x-axis is negative and the area above the x-axis is positive.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

- $\int f(x)\mathop{dx}$ gives the nett *signed* area between the curve
  $y=f(x)$ and the $x$-axis.

  (Signed areas below the $x$-axis are negative.)

  An odd function $f$ is symmetric with respect to the origin,
  so its signed area in the interval $[-a,a]$ is $\displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a}
     f(x)\mathop{dx}$
  $$=\,-\left(\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\mathop{dx}\right)+\int_{0}^{a}
     f(x)\mathop{dx}\,=\,0.$$
- $\int \lvert f(x)\rvert \mathop{dx}$ gives the nett (unsigned) area
  between the curve $y=f(x)$ and the $x$-axis.

  An odd function $f$ is congruent left and right of the
  $y$-axis, so its area in the interval $[-a,a]$ is $\displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a} \lvert f(x)\rvert\mathop{dx}$ $$=\,2\int_{0}^{a} \lvert f(x)\rvert\mathop{dx},$$
  which is generally $> 0.$

Comment: @jwtanner I rolled back the edit not because I mind it, but because you had edited away only one of the two instances of "nett"! (Why bump the page over such a trivial thing though?) I'd deliberately chosen the traditional British spelling, but "net" is fine too.