# How to find area bounded between $x=y^3-y$ and $x=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

Can someone help me with the integration so I can find the area between $x=y^3-y$ and $x=0$?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Also maybe rewriting as the area between $y=x^3-x, y=0$ will feel more familiar.

Comment: I tried ∫[-1,1] (y+1)^3-y dy but I get 0

Comment: You could try integrating from $0$ to $1$ and then double the result

Comment: So if I do this it would be mathematically correct?

Comment: Is the answer 1/2?

Comment: Yes; justify by symmetry

Comment: @ChrisCosta You got zero because that's the signed area. Some ideas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3880873/21813).

Comment: The final answer is 0.5 square units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area bounded between $x=y^3-y$ and $x=0$ is the same as the area bounded between $y=x^3-x$ and $y=0$

$y=x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$

Area bounded between this and $y=0$ is $$\int_{-1}^0 (x^3-x)dx + \bigl|\int_{0}^1 (x^3-x)dx\bigr|$$

**Area cannot be negative,** so absolute value taken above

Final answer will be $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$

**Hope this helps!!**